# CSS floated div, not shrinking to content

Tags: css, css-float

This is very odd to me, and although I've searched, everyone seems to have the opposite problem to me (a floated div shrinking)!

I have this page: http://www.tameside.gov.uk/test/news, which uses PHP to generate the divs at the top for various news stories, and it works fine. However the items (which are floated divs) are in a div which is floated left, which for some reason isn't shrinking to those items (which are it's only contents).

As far as I was aware, a floated div always shrunk to it's contents, but this particular one is expanding to 100% of the page it seems. I've coloured the background of the containing div in grey to show you what I mean.

I want it to shrink to the contents so that I could use a centering trick, and it would then center the div no matter how many divs are in the top news items. But because it's not shrinking, the trick obviously isn't working.

The CSS for each of the news item divs is below:

```css
.news-top-item {
    border-radius: 10px;
    border-color: #3f7dae;
    border-style: solid;
    border-width: 2px;
    float: left;
    width: 19%;
    text-align: center;
    margin-right: 0.5%;
    height: 13em;
    padding-top: 0.5em;
    cursor: pointer;
    position: relative;
}
```

They've also got a span inside that has a little CSS attached to it to make the whole thing a link:

```css
.news-top-item span {
    display: inline;
    position:absolute;
    width:100%;
    height:100%;
    top:0;
    left: 0;
    z-index: 2;
    background-image: url('/tmbc_images/include/1pixel.gif');
    cursor: pointer;
}
```

I doubt that's interfering, but have put it in just in case.

The outer div has only 'float: left' and the background colour applied to it.

Any help would be much appreciated.

Thanks,

James

Comment: Any chance you could drop the relevant parts of the (rendered) HTML and CSS into a [JS Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/), with Lorem-ipsum-ed content if required? That way we can play with it, *and* see the code in one place.

Comment: Hi,

This is the JS Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/W8Dn6/, seems to be doing the same in there too.

Comment: Right, I've made the top-news-item divs fixed width and used JavaScript to dynamically set the width of the containing div and center it using margin: auto.

I've no idea why the original idea isn't working, I was hoping to use this method: http://www.tightcss.com/centering/center_variable_width.htm to center it, thus not needing JavaScript and giving a liquid layout. But for some reason, even that method doesn't work when I make the top items a fixed width (and the float wraps as expected).

If anyone can get it to work with a liquid layout, I'd really appreciate it.

Answer (score 1):

You shall remove float:left and use display:inline-block instead

```
.news-top-item {
    border-radius: 10px;
    border-color: #3f7dae;
    border-style: solid;
    border-width: 2px;
    display:inline-block;
    width: 19%;
    text-align: center;
    margin-right: 0.5%;
    height: 13em;
    padding-top: 0.5em;
    cursor: pointer;
    position: relative;
}
```

And add text-align:center in your containing div

Comment: Hi,

I will try this, but I don't think IE 7 recognises inline-block if I remember correctly, and I need it to work in all browsers, even the terrible ones.

Comment: Hi,

I've tried this solution, and it kind of works, although the divs aren't aligned horizontally anymore, I think the 'whole div link' spans I'm using must be causing some strange behaviour.

Also, as I suspected IE 7 and IE 9 compatibility mode don't understand it. Unfortunately some people are still browsing our site in IE 7, and all employees have their IE defaulting to compatibility mode thanks to Microsoft automatically setting all internal pages to compatibility mode. Therefore this isn't a solution for me.

Comment: Have a look here : http://browsershots.org/http://www.tameside.gov.uk/test/news
Whas it useful ? Then push the answer up to help others ;)

Answer (score 0):

```
width:100%;
height:100%;
```

is 100% of windows size ...
Try

```
width:auto;
height:auto;
```

Comment: Do you mean in the spans? The spans are only 100% of the divs, the idea of them is to make the divs links. But they shouldn't be encroaching past the news item divs which contain those spans.

I'll try adding an auto width to the container and see if that helps

Comment: Hi,

I tried adding width: auto to the containers, but that only works in IE 9 compatibility mode, so is not a solution I'm afraid.

Answer (score 0):

use absolute units instead of percentages to define measurements for the inner elements:

```css
.news-top-item {
    border-radius: 10px;
    border-color: #3f7dae;
    border-style: solid;
    border-width: 2px;
    float: left;
    width: 200px; /* <--- */
    text-align: center;
    margin-right: 2px; /* <--- */
    height: 13em;
    padding-top: 0.5em;
    cursor: pointer;
    position: relative;
}
```

Comment: Hi,

Thanks for this, for some reason, it works. Do you know why it works with pixels and not percents? Ideally I would want it to be liquid, not fixed, so if anyone can get it to work with the percentages I'd appreciate it.